# How to get value of a label in li element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, label, local-storage, html-lists

I am new to JavaScript. I am building a TODO application as a project after completing online tutorials.

I have a structure in HTML like this:

```
<ul id="list">
            <li class="myCheck"><input type="checkbox" id="check"> 
            <label>Gym</label></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I am adding more li elements using JS, then storing it in `localStorage` using JSON. Then there is an option to remove TODO from the list.

How do I get the text value of label element so that I can remove it from the JSON?

Comment: Can you show how are you storing it in `localStorage`?

Comment: Can you share more code, how do you add <li> elements and how do you remove it? I would use an ID for <li> element and add/remove by this id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You.
You may try following:

HTML :

```
<ul id="list">
            <li class="myCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="Gym" value="Gym"> Gym

            </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript :

```
$(".myCheck").on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").val();
  // or $(this).sblings().find(":checkbox").val()
  // or $(this).prev().find(":checkbox").val()
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: #try this above one, hopefully this will work for you.:)